# Check if a variable is in POWER base + PHP

Tags: php, math

I want to check if an input variable is in POWER base.

For example :

Input : 25 ;//yes in power pow(5,2)
Input : 26 ;//no not in power

I made a code but its time taking

```
$var = 25;
$half = round($var / 2);
for($x = 0; $x <= $half; $x++){
    for($y = 0; $y <= $half; $y++){
        if(pow($x, $y) === $var){
            $output = "1";
        }
    }
}
if(!$output){
    echo "0";
}else{
    echo "1";
}
```

Comment: Whats the problem??? May be you need to break on match of your if condition. [Example](https://3v4l.org/f13Dr)

Comment: Also define **$output = 0;** at beginning otherwise it will show "Undefined variable: output".

Comment: Well, in this case if I entered some big value like 15625 and it will taking time because of $half. any suggestion ? ? ?

Comment: check my simplified answer is this what you need ? or you need base and power too ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`sqrt`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqrt.php) which will return square root of given number, then just check if the returned value is in decimal or not.

```
$var = 25;
$sqrt = sqrt($var);
if($sqrt !== floor( $sqrt )) {
    echo 'no power';
} else {
    echo 'power';
}
```